# In BDD, should scenarios be abstract descriptions of behvaior, or should they contain concrete examples?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, bdd, scenarios

I feel I have reached a fundamental dilemma in writing BDD scenarios as a tester.

When writing BDD scenarios from testing perspective, I tend to end up using concrete examples with concrete data and observing the state, i.e. Given these initial values, when user performs an action, then these final values should be observed.

Example with an initial dataset given in background:

```
Background:
  Given following items are in the store
    | type   | name | X  | Y    | Z    | tags |
    | single | el1  | 10 | 20   | 1.03 | t1   |
    | multi  | el2  | 10 | 20   | 30   | t2   |
    | single | el3  | 10 | 3.02 | 30   | t3   |

Scenario: Adding tag to multi-type item
  Given Edit Item Popup is opened for item: el2
  When user adds tag NEWTAG
  And user clicks on Apply changes button
  Then item store should display following items
    | type   | name | X  | Y    | Z    | tags       |
    | single | el1  | 10 | 20   | 1.03 | t1         |
    | multi  | el2  | 10 | 20   | 30   | t2, NEWTAG |
    | single | el3  | 10 | 3.02 | 30   | t3         |
```

The initial dataset from Background can be reused in all (or most) scenarios that deal with modifying and adding/deleting items, in relation to particular feature. I can also iterate the scenario over some data set that explores the problem space, boundary conditions etc. (trivial example here: tags with too many or forbidden chars).

But when requirements are not entirely clear I sometimes go with a different approach and start from a more abstract description of the behavior (so that scenarios can become the specification), which seems to me as the more (for lack of a better word) correct way of doing BDD. So I end up with behavior descriptions which are perfectly clear when a human is reading them from the requirement analysis position, but appear to be extremely vague when you shift to testing perspective:

```
Scenario: Adding tag to multi-type item
  Given Edit Item Popup is opened for multi-type item
  When user adds a new tag
  And user clicks on Apply changes button
  Then that item should have that tag displayed in item store
```

For some reason I feel way better writing a scenario like that, as it seems closer to BDD ideals (describing the behavior, doh!). But at the same time I feel terrible because of 2 reasons:

1. A lot of details are implicit here and thus hidden deep in the implementation. Because of that, while implementing, we need to ask ourselves a ton of questions like 'what initial data should I use here?', 'how to keep track of which item are we handling?', 'how deep should I examine the final state?'. This all goes away when you just compare final state with a reference table, as in the first approach.
2. (Possibly more serious) I am not exploring the problem space here at all, while bugs often await us somewhere in dark corners of that space.

One could argue that these 2 approaches I presented are just extreme ends of a spectrum, but I still see them fundamentally different, and often find myself wondering which approach to chose.

So, how do you write your BDD (test) scenarios? Data-driven and state-comparing, or full blown abstract descriptions of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

After long time I finally stumbled into an interesting article that touches the same topic as I raised here, and partially answers my question:
https://specflow.org/challenges/extra-cases-and-exceptions/

One of the key points from this article for me was that there are professionals that recognize this issue and one possible way forward is, according to them, to just create two scenarios (or two sets of scenarios): one human-oriented rule descriptions, and another one exploring the problem space with more examples.